# Correlating distance between bars in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a bar graph right now, and it's similar to the one here in terms of format http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6872226, with the "x - axis" on the left and the "y-axis" on the bottom. I have certain numbers on the left as my "categories" like 3048, 3060, 3096... etc. Each of these categories is a number and each of them has some sort of difference.

I was wondering, how would I make the bar graph so that each category isn't evenly spaced? Right now, I have `rangeroundbands` which makes them all evenly spaced, but I'm trying to make it so that the distance between the bars correlates to the number difference between the categories. For example, assuming 3048, 3096, 4050, the distance between 3048 and 3096 would be less than the distance between 3096 and 4050, visual enough to tell but also doesn't make the bar graph impossibly large.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.extent(molecules_0, function(d) {
        return parseInt(d.molweight);
    }))
    .rangeRoundBands([padding, height - padding]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(2)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
        return molecules_0[i].molweight;
    })
    .tickValues(d3.range(20));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to modify the Y axis. Currently it simply uses the length of the `categories` array:

```
var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,categories.length])
    .range([0,480]);
```

All you really have to do is to change the input of the domain:

```
    .domain(d3.extent(categories))
```

So that your Y position will also be based off the category value.

Comment: Hi, this was what I was looking for. I did this on my graph, and now it seems like the y axis is causing some issues, namely returning  d3.js:670 Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(0,NaN)"  . I'm guessing this is because the scale has been manipulated, which might be causing some trouble. I attached my code above for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You want to target the y attribute of the SVG `rect` elements. Assuming your categories is an array like [ 3048, 3060, 3096 ], you can set the y attribute to categories[i + 1] - categories[i].

The above does not work at the last element of your array because [i+1] will be undefined. You can wrap the statement in a ternary so that if i === 0 it simply returns zero (since 0 is falsy). That would look like this:

```
i ? categories[i+1] - categories[i] : 0
```

If it is easier, you can create a "differences" array like so: [ 0, 12, 36 ]. This might be more easy to deal with and you can reuse it when you calculate the position of the tick marks. (See D3 documentation on **[axis.tickValues([values])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues)**. You can provide an array to control the axis tick positions).

You might also have to add a bit of padding (`somePadding`). The default padding was 19.

See suggested revision below:

```
var chart = canvas.append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
    .attr('id','bars')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(dollars)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('height',19)
    //.attr({'x':0,'y':function(d,i){ return yscale(i)+19; }})
    // modify the y attribute of each SVG rect element
    .attr({'x':0,'y':function(d,i){ return yscale(i) + (i ? categories[i+1] - categories[i] : 0) + somePadding; }})
        .style('fill',function(d,i){ return colorScale(i); })
        .attr('width',function(d){ return 0; });
```